автоудаление сообщений, истории
В телеграм есть стандартная функция - автоудаление сообщений чата.
Как настроить в боте в aiogram так же, чтобы в общем история в чате хранилась только одни сутки, например.

Штатными средствами никак. Костыль - запоминать все айдишники сообщений в конкретном чат айди и по расписанию их удалять. Но помнится мне, там нехилые таймауты у тг на удаление сообщений.

Для настройки автоудаления сообщений в чате с помощью бота на aiogram можно использовать следующий подход:

Импортируйте необходимые библиотеки:
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, types
from datetime import datetime, timedelta


Создать функцию, которая будет удалять сообщения старше одного дня:
async def delete_old_messages(bot: Bot, chat_id: int):
"""
Функция для удаления сообщений старше 1 дня в указанном чате.
"""
one_day_ago = datetime.now() - timedelta(days=1)
async for message in bot.get_chat_history(chat_id):
    if message.date < one_day_ago:
        try:
        await bot.delete_message(chat_id, message.message_id)
    except:
        pass


Вызывайте эту функцию периодически, например, каждый день:
from aiogram.utils.executor import start_polling
async def on_startup(dp: Dispatcher):
    print('Bot started')
    chat_id = 'YOUR_CHAT_ID'  # Замените на ID вашего чата
    while True:
        await delete_old_messages(dp.bot, chat_id)
        await asyncio.sleep(86400)  # Ждем 1 день перед следующим вызовом

if __name__ == '__main__':
    start_polling(on_startup)



Попробуйте такой подход, и не забудьте подставить нужные вам значения. (Всё сработает, если у бота есть права на удаление).
